# Published a google tag manager version but it still shows unpublished changes and cannot search my published tags

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, tag-manager

Something weird is happening.

I have published a GTM version with some new events but it is still showing as unpublished changes. Although the events are live and I can see them in real time being triggered.

Moreover I cannot find the tags in GTM anymore.

Any idea why this must be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me once.

You might have restored an older version which did not have the tags, but the tags are live in another version. it causes the tags to be live but you not able to see the tags in the container.

Restore the live version as 'Edit as a new version' and you should see your tags back.